# Navigation using real time generate map without a known map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I know this should be possible but at the point of using AMCL. I don`t know what to do as AMCL does not have a tutorial with no known map.
Right now in the robot configuration.launch**

**A map generated, and current laser scan data can be seen in the rviz.
Then I follows navigation tutorial to write configuration for navigation stack
**

the other yaml file are all the same except that
at global_costmap_params.yaml
static_map is set to false

amcl_diff.launch is similiar to the one found in
drh-robotics-ros - Revision 108: /trunk/ros/ardros/launch

But I got problem for the last part move_base.launch
map server is need to run navigation stack which operates on the known map

This part specific ask a known map for processing where as I need it to use the /map generated by slam_gmapping. And I`ll need it to be real time.

I know I have to change 
to a real time map generated by slam_gmapping. But I don`t know how to do it as there wasn`t much info out of here amcl/Tutorials

Does any one knows how to do it? How to modify the last move_base.launch to read real time map data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49841/navigation-using-real-time-generate-map-without-a-known-map/) by [snakehaihai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3261/snakehaihai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL is meant for localization only (based on a known map) and will not work with a non-static map. SLAM (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping) methods are meant for the task you're looking at. Options for that are [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping) and (shameless plug :) ) [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping).

I suppose you could look into hacking AMCL to work with a map generated online by some other approach, but for that other approach to be able to generate a consistent map you need localization. And that's the chicken-egg problem of SLAM ;)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6